# Django - How to display a attribut (name) from forgeinKey object?

Tags: python, django, relation, many-to-one

I have an artist which has many paintings, so a many to one relation. So i got

```
class Artist(models.Model):
    name   = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    age    = models.IntField()

class Paintings(models.Model):
    painting         = models.ImageField()
    painting_name    = models.CharField(max_length=120, default='', null=True)
    artist = models.ForeignKey(
       'Artist',
       related_name='paintings',
       on_delete=models.CASCADE,
       verbose_name= 'Künstler'
    )
```

Now if I'll create a new Painting rely to an artist it doesnt show me the exact name of the artist, just the artist object [id]*[image: artist object [id]]*

inside my `admin.py` I try to define

```
artist = Artist.name 
list_display = ('image_tag', artist, 'painting_name')
```

but this is not allowed. So how can I replace the *Artist Object (id)* with the actual `name` of the artist?

Comment: override `__str__` in `Artist` model, it simply tells django how to print and convert the object to a string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `Artist` model you must define a `__str__` function:

```
def __str__(self):
  return self.name # Or whatever way you want your Artist to show
```

This tells `Django` how to to print that object.

**From the [Django Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/instances/):**

`__str__()`

The `__str__()` method is called whenever you call `str()` on an object. Django uses `str(obj)` in a number of places. Most notably, to display an object in the Django admin site and as the value inserted into a template when it displays an object. Thus, you should always return a nice, human-readable representation of the model from the `__str__()` method.